# Update of Mongodb using pymongo gets slows dramatically as works way through the file

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I created this to upload stock price data to Mongodb. It creates a bunch of hourly documents for all stocks and  the hours of the trading day in the csv file. It then updates these documents with data from the CSV file. So each document will eventually contain 1min,5min,30min and 60 min data for each stock name for each hour in a seperate document(time series data).

The code bulk_writes 5000 updates at a time. The first update of 5000 takes 0.7sec the last one (on 1 days data 650,000 updates approx) 80 secs. total 90 minutes to load 650k updates. However if i use a different days data the first write can take 50 secs with each one getting slower. I am using Mongodb community 4.2. I used bulk writes after just doing individual updates but it seemed to make little difference.

Can anyone tell me why it gets so slow after the initial writes and why CSV files not at the top of the directory seem to go so much slower? I check to make sure that the pymongo.has_c at the start. I have tried running mongodb --nojournal. I am new to python and mongodb. I have included a small sample of the output at the bottom. Thanks for any assistance

https://www.screencast.com/t/fEiR2pxpTgHG
https://www.screencast.com/t/y5RSmx2hISE

```
from pymongo import MongoClient, UpdateOne
import pymongo
import csv
from datetime import datetime
import logging
import shutil
import time 



def startmongo():
    client = MongoClient('localhost',27017)
    db = client.test
    global coll
    coll = db.test1
    z=pymongo.has_c()
    print(z)

def importmongo(filename):

    with open('D:/msjho/Downloads/FP/Intraday NYSE Sept/'+ filename, 'r') as file:
        data = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')

        row1 =next(data) #access first row data
        print(row1)
        """ use the correct date format"""
        try:
            date = datetime.strptime(row1[1] , '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
        except ValueError:
            date = datetime.strptime(row1[1] , '%d-%b-%Y %H:%M')

        date = date.replace(minute=0)
        tickers=[]


        for row in data:
            if row[0] not in tickers:
                tickers.append(row[0])
        no_stocks =len(tickers)

        """ ensure 1st and last tickers on correct have already been place store in the DB """

        x = (coll.find_one({"date": date, "ticker": tickers[0]},{"ticker":1,"_id":0}))
        y = (coll.find_one({"date": date, "ticker": tickers[-1]},{"ticker":1,"_id":0}))

        if x == {"ticker":tickers[0]} and y == {"ticker":tickers[-1]}:
            print(tickers[0])
            return ('its already there')

        print('Loading up initial documents')
        logging. info('number of companies in ' + filename + ' '+ str(no_stocks))
        no_doc = 0
        for ticker in tickers:
            for hours in range(9,17):
                date1 = date.replace(hour=hours)
                coll.insert_one({"ticker": ticker,"date":date1})
                #x+=1
            no_doc +=1

        logging.info('number of companies inserted to Mdb ' + filename + ' '+ str(no_doc))

def updatePriceInfo(filename):

    with open('D:/msjho/Downloads/FP/Intraday NYSE Sept/'+ filename, 'r') as file:
        data = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')

        ''' work out if its a 1min,5min,30min or 60 min file'''

        if filename[-5]=='1':
            filetype ='1min'

        elif filename[-5] == '5':
            filetype ='5min'

        elif filename[-5] == '0':
            if filename[-6] == '3':
                filetype ='30min'
            elif filename[-6] == '6':
                filetype ='60min'

        r = 0

        start = time.time()
        operations =[]

        for row in data:

            """ write 5000 updates at a time"""

            if len(operations) == 5000:
                coll.bulk_write(operations, ordered = False)
                end = time.time()
                r+=1
                print('ops is now'+ str(r)+' '+str(end-start))
                operations =[]

                """ use the correct date format"""
            try:
                date = datetime.strptime(row[1] , '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
            except ValueError:
                date = datetime.strptime(row[1] , '%d-%b-%Y %H:%M')

            mins = date.minute
            placeset = filetype +'.'+ str(mins)

            updatedate = date.replace(minute =0)  #change date so can be used to find update document in update query

            if row[5] > row[2]:
                direction = 1 #ticker rose in time period
            elif row[5]< row[2]:
                direction = 0 #ticker fell in time period
            else:
                direction = 2 #ticker finished equal


            operations.append(UpdateOne({"ticker":row[0], "date": updatedate}, 
                             {"$set":
                                 {placeset:
                                     { "p":[row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5]],"v":row[6],"d":direction
                                      }, 
                                 }  
                            },upsert = True))


        #logging.info('number of rows(prices) inserted from ' + filename + ' ' + str(rw) + ' insert complete\n\n' )
        if ( len(operations) > 0 ):
            coll.bulk_write(operations,ordered=False)
        print('finished')     

if __name__ == '__main__': 

    #logging.basicConfig(filename="D:\msjho\Downloads\Logs\importstockdata.log", level=logging.INFO)
    filename = 'NYSE_20190903_1.csv'
    startmongo()
    importmongo(filename)
    updatePriceInfo(filename)
```

Comment: As you can see from this screen capture the code works and fills in all the fields but it would take many hours just to insert one days data which makes me think i am doing something fundamentally wrong.  https://www.screencast.com/t/6HaThyzy8Cp

Comment: Change the mongoclient so writeconcern = 0  client = MongoClient('localhost',27017,w=0) this speeds it up hugely but it only gets about 25,000 updates .....then it goes on strike for a few minutes then another quickblast(see below).  Will try multiprocessing as python maybe the blockage.    https://www.screencast.com/t/ewsTaa9y

Comment: Do you have any indexes on the collection?

Comment: Ummm duh...i think you maybe right. I create 24,000 documents then start updating them without creating an index. As i update more and more documents the whole thing grinds to a halt.  I will try it out tomorrow. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any indexes then I would recommend creating one as follows:

```
db.coll.createIndex( { "ticker": 1, "date": 1 } )
```

Comment: Yep thanks gave it a try last night....90 secs to load the updates down from minimum 90 mins.

Comment: In pymongo i found it wants the fields and order passed in as tuples, so something like this ''' coll.create_index([( "ticker", pymongo.ASCENDING), ("date", pymongo.ASCENDING )] )'''

Comment: For sure. But you only need to do this once, so running it at the shell is perfectly adequate.